# Are there any good tutorials or examples on how to use Java ObjectPool/pools?

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I am trying to create a pool of channels/connections to a queue server and was trying to use ObjectPool but am having trouble using it from the [example](http://commons.apache.org/pool/examples.html) on their site.

So far I have threads that do work but I want each of them to grab a channel from the pool and then return it.  I understand how to use it(borrowObject/returnObjects) but not sure how to create the intial pool.

Here's how channels are made in rabbitmq:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
```

and my code just uses channel to do stuff.  I'm confused because the only example I could find (on their site) starts it like this:

```
private ObjectPool<StringBuffer> pool;

    public ReaderUtil(ObjectPool<StringBuffer> pool) { 
        this.pool = pool;
    }
```

Which does not make sense to me.  I realized this is common to establishing database connections so I tried to find tutorials using databases and ObjectPool but they seem to use DBCP which is specific to databases(and I can't seem to use the logic for my queue server).

Any suggestions on how to use it? Or is there a another approach used for pools in java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They create a class that creates objects & knows what to do when they are returned. That might be something like this for you:

```
public class PoolConnectionFactory extends BasePoolableObjectFactory<Connection> { 

    private final ConnectionFactory factory;
    public PoolConnectionFactory() {
        factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
    }

    // for makeObject we'll simply return a new Connection
    public Connection makeObject() { 
        return factory.newConnection();
    } 

    // when an object is returned to the pool,  
    // we'll clear it out 
    public void passivateObject(Connection con) { 
        con.I_don't_know_what_to_do(); 
    } 

    // for all other methods, the no-op  
    // implementation in BasePoolableObjectFactory 
    // will suffice 
}
```

now you create a `ObjectPool<Connection>` somewhere:

```
ObjectPool<Connection> pool = new StackObjectPool<Connection>(new PoolConnectionFactory());
```

then you can use `pool` inside your threads like

```
Connection c = pool.borrowObject();
c.doSomethingWithMe();
pool.returnObject(c);
```

The lines that don't make sense to you are a way to pass the pool object to a different class. See last line, they create the pool while creating the reader.

```
new ReaderUtil(new StackObjectPool<StringBuffer>(new StringBufferFactory()))
```

Comment: wow thanks so much. I'll play with the code.  I don't understand where to specify the number of channels. In your example are you sharing one connection or there a place I can say I want to pre-create X connections?

Comment: Pools do not precreate their pooled object. They create them on demand and take them either from the pool or create a fresh one if the pool is empty. So there is usually no limit. But I don't know how the classes you use or the pool class work / what they are capable of. I just translated the example for you :)

Comment: GenericObjectPool will pre-create pooled objects if you enable the eviction thread and set the "minIdle" property. http://commons.apache.org/pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the idea better. Does it make sense to have objects created on demand? or pre populate them?  Doesn't it defeat the point of having an on-demand object created if I could simply do the same in my class?  Once it creates the on demand object do they persist for a while in the pool or do they die right away(if they persist can I set the lifespan of them)?

Comment: The pool is like a cache, if you put enough objects back you don't need to create new. And exactly that is the point of a pool - not creating new objects if you can reuse them. And they don't die in there they just stay there.

Comment: Does that mean I'll always have as many connections open as my highest peak even after threadexecutor reduces the number of threads I have?

Comment: I don't know how that pool exactly behaves / how you should use / configure it in your case :(

Comment: No worries, I'm learning so I'll play with the code.  I am getting errors though. Your code above times out eventually because I spawn many threads and connections start to time out, but I want channels(which are spawned from connections) but I get null exceptions. I modified your code to this(similar to the process in my sample code in the question):

Comment: `class PoolConnectionFactory extends BasePoolableObjectFactory<Channel> { 

    private final ConnectionFactory factory;
    private Connection connection;
    public PoolConnectionFactory() throws IOException {
        factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        connection = factory.newConnection();
         
    }

    // for makeObject we'll simply return a new Connection
    public Channel makeObject() throws IOException { 
      return connection.createChannel();

    } `

Comment: just went through my debugger and it seems its creating new connections for each thread and not spawning new channels(within an existing connection) the way I'm doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a custom implementation of PoolableObjectFactory to create, validate, and destroy the objects you want to pool. Then pass an instance of your factory to an ObjectPool's contructor and you're ready to start borrowing objects.

Here's some sample code. You can also look at the source code for commons-dbcp, which uses commons-pool.

```
import org.apache.commons.pool.BasePoolableObjectFactory;
import org.apache.commons.pool.ObjectPool;
import org.apache.commons.pool.PoolableObjectFactory;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool;

public class PoolExample {
    public static class MyPooledObject {
        public MyPooledObject() {
            System.out.println("hello world");
        }

        public void sing() {
            System.out.println("mary had a little lamb");
        }

        public void destroy() {
            System.out.println("goodbye cruel world");
        }
    }

    public static class MyPoolableObjectFactory extends BasePoolableObjectFactory<MyPooledObject> {
        @Override
        public MyPooledObject makeObject() throws Exception {
            return new MyPooledObject();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyObject(MyPooledObject obj) throws Exception {
            obj.destroy();
        }
        // PoolableObjectFactory has other methods you can override
        // to valdiate, activate, and passivate objects.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PoolableObjectFactory<MyPooledObject> factory = new MyPoolableObjectFactory();
        ObjectPool<MyPooledObject> pool = new GenericObjectPool<MyPooledObject>(factory);

        // Other ObjectPool implementations with special behaviors are available;
        // see the JavaDoc for details

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                MyPooledObject obj;

                try {
                    obj = pool.borrowObject();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // failed to borrow object; you get to decide how to handle this
                    throw e;
                }

                try {
                    // use the pooled object
                    obj.sing();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // this object has failed us -- never use it again!
                    pool.invalidateObject(obj);
                    obj = null; // don't return it to the pool

                    // now handle the exception however you want

                } finally {
                    if (obj != null) {
                        pool.returnObject(obj);
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            pool.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to follow your example and implement Object pooling. I am using commons-pool2-2.1 but my import for class `BasePoolableObjectFactory` doesn't work. Even the simple StringBufferFactory example from [commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool2/examples.html) example doesn't work. However, all other imports related to pool2 works fine. 
It's probably something super simple that I am missing. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ellipsis I haven't looked at commons-pool2 yet. I would recommend starting a new Question and posting all the details of your issue.